# Swift 3 Custom Cell Changing on scroll

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift3

Sorry, I know this is a repeat question, but I have not been able to understand the answer from the other questions.

My custom cell is changing on scrolling. I know it is due to the reuse identifier, but I don't know how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated. I'm using indexPath.row to access an array as well.

**How do I get my table view to not change values on scroll, even through I'm using a reuse identifier?**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell : TeamCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TeamCell", for: indexPath) as! TeamCell

    cell.trainer.image = UIImage(named: "t\(Player.User.Gold.trainers[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].imageID)")
    if Player.User.Gold.trainers[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].p1.name != 0 {
        cell.pokemon1.image = UIImage(named: "\(Player.User.Gold.trainers[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].p1.name)")
        cell.pokemon1.isHidden = false
    } else {
        cell.pokemon1.isHidden = true
    }
    if Player.User.Gold.trainers[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].p2.name != 0 {
        cell.pokemon2.image = UIImage(named: "\(Player.User.Gold.trainers[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].p2.name)")
        cell.pokemon1.isHidden = false
    } else {
        cell.pokemon2.isHidden = true
    }
    if Player.User.Gold.trainers[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].p3.name != 0 {
        cell.pokemon3.image = UIImage(named: "\(Player.User.Gold.trainers[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].p3.name)")
        cell.pokemon1.isHidden = false
    } else {
        cell.pokemon3.isHidden = true
    }
    if Player.User.Gold.trainers[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].p4.name != 0 {
        cell.pokemon4.image = UIImage(named: "\(Player.User.Gold.trainers[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].p4.name)")
        cell.pokemon1.isHidden = false
    } else {
        cell.pokemon4.isHidden = true
    }
    if Player.User.Gold.trainers[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].p5.name != 0 {
        cell.pokemon5.image = UIImage(named: "\(Player.User.Gold.trainers[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].p5.name)")
        cell.pokemon1.isHidden = false
    } else {
        cell.pokemon5.isHidden = true
    }
    if Player.User.Gold.trainers[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].p6.name != 0 {
        cell.pokemon6.image = UIImage(named: "\(Player.User.Gold.trainers[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].p6.name)")
        cell.pokemon1.isHidden = false
    } else {
        cell.pokemon6.isHidden = true
    }

    return cell
}
```

(the function just checks if the value of an array is 0, if it isn't then show the image)

Comment: why are you setting pok1 in every if to hidden= flase? Shouldnt it be the pokemon your setting the inmage?

Comment: I made a rookie mistake, not changing the proper values in the if statements! Whoopsie

Comment: yes that fixed it! My face is red, thanks aha

Comment: awsome, have fun coding ... oh and one advice, read the trainer data once and put it in a variable, so ucan use only this variable int the bext conditions and dont need to get it every time again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so like the comments says the problem was the wrong vissibly setting of pokemon1 in every if.

**edit**

well because of the downvote i will be more precice:
In every if condition u set the pokemon1 to vissible. You need to use the Pokomen that your setting as image.

have fun coding

Answer (score 1):

Set your every pokemon `images` to `nil` or some common `placeholder image` immediate after `dequeue` the cell, then put your every `if-conditions` and set every image view's default hidden property also, like if your imageview is hidden by default then set it's hidden property to `true` before setting images in `if` condition!

Comment: well, this is only a different implementation than he has. I think the problem is the wrong pokemon to set vissible on every if

Comment: Tableview resuse the cells, so if for particular cell if there is no image available then it shows older image which have been set for previous cell! so making it nil, will make imageview's image nil every time and if there is no image available for cell then it will remains nil or some placeholder image!

Comment: but he is setting it to hidden = false